# Rxweb - How to bind data to formGroup which has @propArray decorator

Tags: angular, formbuilder, formgroups

I am using [rxweb-reactive-form-validators](https://docs.rxweb.io/getting-started) for my project.

I searched everywhere but didn't found any solution for my question, so posting it here.

When I tried to bind server data using fromGroup method

`this.form = this.rxFormBuilder.formGroup(Model, serverData);`

I am getting below error when my model contains @propArray decorator-

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'properties' of undefined
> at RxFormBuilder.push../node_modules/@rxweb/reactive-form-validators/fesm5/rxweb-reactive-form-validators.js.RxFormBuilder.checkObjectPropAdditionalValidation (rxweb-reactive-form-validators.js:4219)
> at RxFormBuilder.push../node_modules/@rxweb/reactive-form-validators/fesm5/rxweb-reactive-form-validators.js.RxFormBuilder.formGroup (rxweb-reactive-form-validators.js:4479)
> at rxweb-reactive-form-validators.js:4551

Here is how my model looks like -

```
export class Model {

@prop()
id = '';

@propArray(QuestionModel)
questions: QuestionModel[]; // For this I am getting error.
}
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: it would be great if you could which serverData are you trying to bind

Answer (score 1):

I am also dealing with issues with rxweb propArray but while researching my issue I think I might have happened on a solution for your issue.
I figured I would help even though I am not an expert on rxweb but the owners of the lib  don't respond to questions often even though they tell us to submit to stack overflow.

```
export class Model {

@prop()
id = '';

@propArray(QuestionModel,{createBlank: true})
questions: QuestionModel[]; // For this I am getting error.
// or
@propArray(QuestionModel)
questions: QuestionModel[] = []; // Int the array first.
}
```